Multiple Errors Installing exllamav2 and nmslib in a Conda Environment
I am experiencing multiple issues when setting up and running the exllamav2 and nmslib packages in a Conda environment. Below is a detailed account of the steps I've taken, the environment
configuration, and the errors encountered:
Environment Setup
Creation of Conda Environment:

conda create -n llm python=3.10

Environment Variables and Compiler Verification:
Checked the CUDA_HOME environment variable:


(llm) C:\WINDOWS\system32>echo %CUDA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8

Verified the C/C++ compiler setup:


(llm) C:\Windows\System32>cl
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.41.34120 for x64

Checked the Ninja build system version:

        (llm) C:\Windows\System32>ninja --version
        1.12.1

Package Installation

    Installation of PyTorch and Related Packages:


    conda install pytorch==2.0.1 torchvision==0.15.2 torchaudio==2.0.2 pytorch-cuda=11.8 -c pytorch -c nvidia

Installation of exllamav2:

        pip install exllamav2==0.0.8

    Attempt to Install nmslib:
        Issue: Unable to install nmslib  ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (nmslib)

when I try import exllamav2
    Error message:

AttributeError: module 'distutils' has no attribute '_msvccompiler'

when I re-run the cell I get this error instead
Error message:

    ImportError: DLL load failed while importing exllamav2_ext: The specified module could not be found.

Questions:
How can I resolve the AttributeError related to distutils and the ImportError for the missing DLL in exllamav2_ext?
What steps should I take to successfully install nmslib in this environment, considering the issues I'm encountering with other installations?

Additional Information:
Operating System: Windows 10


Try installing the packages with setuptools < 74.0.0: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/4657

I did try this setuptools==59.5.0 but I will try your recommendation. thank you
